# Converting VB DATEADD() function into a PHP equivalent

Tags: php, datetime, vbscript

I need to convert the following lines into PHP but not sure of the DATEADD() equivalent and how the parameters need to be displayed.

This is the script which has had the IF ELSE statement slightly modified for PHP:

```
if ($period == '1 month') 
        $finish = DATEADD(m, 1, $start);

    else if ($period == '1 year') 
        $finish = DATEADD(yy, 1, $start);

    else
        $finish = DATEADD(d, 1, $start);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime).

```
<?php

$start = time(); // your time origin
$result = strtotime("+1 month", $start); // respects 28/30/31 days
$result = strtotime("next monday", $start); // getting silly…
```

-- edit --

If you like objects, you can also give [DateTime::add()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) a shot. Not sure why this would be better than the strtotime approach, though.

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime();
$start->add(new DateInterval("P1M")); // add 1 month
```

Comment: the `DateTime::add()` method is better than `strtotime()` because `strtotime()` is an old function that tries to do everything. It is very slow and has some nasty quirks, whereas `DateTime::add()` is much newer and quicker and less quirky. You don't even have to use it as an object; you can simply call `date_add()` for the non-OO way of calling the same function.

Comment: What quirks with strtotime() are you talking about, @Spudley?

Comment: There's a lot of bad stuff about `strtotime()`. For a start, there's the scary way it deals with the ambiguity between `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` formats. Then there's outright bugs like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724954/php-strtotime-first-monday-february-returns-second-monday-if-february-1st-is